# Hot shoe flash units and softboxes for portraits; good beginner setup?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, lighting

Taking a previous question ([Advice for someone just entering the world of off-camera flash?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/60657/advice-for-someone-just-entering-the-world-of-off-camera-flash)) and breaking it into pieces, as was suggested to me for more effective answering.

I'm a student photographer looking to get into off-camera flash for portraits, using hot shoe flash units, specifically.

I was hoping someone here might be able to outline a cost-effective, simple setup for me. I'm not sure how to best go about assembling a system; that is, whether I should get each piece individually, or buy a prefab kit.

My thinking right now is to get an 8x9" softbox to start, and use it with my 430 ex II speedlite, then possibly acquire another speedlite and an umbrella down the road.

I'm not sure that 8x9" is big enough, but also don't want such a large soft box that my speedlite isn't strong enough. Would this be a good route for me to take, starting out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on my experience (in part based on what I learned from asking [Are small on-flash softboxes useful, or a gimmick?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/13310/are-small-on-flash-softboxes-useful-or-a-gimmick) a few years ago), an 8x9" softbox is really going to be too small to be generally useful for portraits. You can use it for headshots, if you get in tight and have it just out of frame, but it's not very versatile otherwise — at least not as the main light source. (As a supplementary tool it can, as the answers to the other questions note, be better than nothing. You can use it for dramatic effect, for example.)

I have a set of [Westcott Rapid Box](http://www.fjwestcott.com/light-modifiers/rapid-box/rapid-box-speedlites) small collapsible softboxes (in both the "strip" and "octa" configurations). These are basically just one size category up from what you're looking at, and I think really the minimum size to consider. If you have the space, I'd go a bit larger.

One of your primary concerns is that your 430 EX II flash doesn't have enough power for this. At the Rapid Box size, I don't think this is a concern; I'm using [Cheetah Light V850](https://www.cheetahstand.com/product-p/cl-v850.htm)s, which are cheaper and dumber than that flash but provide about one more stop of nominal power, and I often use them at ¹⁄₄ or ¹⁄₈th power (or even less). And with today's modern sensors, if you *need* more power than your flash has, you can easily compensate by raising ISO a little bit without meaningful quality loss.

As you can see in my experiments at [Does the wide-angle diffuser on a flash help reduce hotspots when used in a small softbox?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/48313/does-the-wide-angle-diffuser-on-a-flash-help-reduce-hotspots-when-used-in-a-smal), my flash has enough power and spread (with a push-on diffuser) to "fill" the softbox. Also, even though they're bigger than the 8×9", you *still* really will mostly use them just out of frame [to get the most benefit](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/52448/how-to-get-beautiful-even-and-soft-lighting-on-face/52450#52450), which means that you're close enough that you don't need a lot of power. So basically, I'd cross this off your list of concerns.

You can also go for a shoot-through umbrella, which is an easy way to get a large diffuser cheaply. In my experience, though, they're awkward and harder to use, and basically not worth it overall. (See [Will two lights plus octaboxes be a good starter setup for portrait photography, or can I get away with one umbrella?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/59885/will-two-lights-plus-octaboxes-be-a-good-starter-setup-for-portrait-photography?rq=1) and [What is the difference between a softbox and a shoot-through umbrella?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/853/what-is-the-difference-between-a-softbox-and-a-shoot-through-umbrella)) The Westcott products I linked are a little pricey, and you can find generic equivalents easily too. These are nicely made, though, and have an advantage over most softboxes designed for flash because they're made for the flash body to sit outside of the back of the box, making it easier to adjust any settings you need to tweak or to change batteries.

Even then, tweaking stuff at the flash is *kinda tedious*. You definitely want something that will let you control flash power from the camera. For years I used the built-in wireless flash control of my camera (Pentax's P-TTL), but when I started to get serious about learning how to do studio-style portraits, I found that I really wanted manual control. Automatic TTL just doesn't add much when the situation isn't going to change on its own and when mostly you are concerned with adjusting the ratio between different lights. There are a number of systems that will give you this — I went with the Cheetah Lights I linked above as a low-cost option, or you could choose something like the [PocketWizard](http://www.pocketwizard.com/products/transmitter_receiver/flextt5-canon/) system, or you could go with Canon's own [new radio system](http://www.learn.usa.canon.com/app/pdfs/quickguides/CDLC_Speedlite_600EX-RT_Radio_Setup_QuickGuide.pdf). (In a small studio or in a makeshift environment with a lot of light spill, you can get away with optical wireless, and Canon's version of that does allow remote manual power control, so in the interest of budget control and making use of the flash you already have, could start with that and expand to radio later if you decide it'll help.)

Comment: Ok, awesome! Thanks for the detailed response. As a student, I really appreciate that.

Comment: Good point. Removed for now.

Comment: Great answer again Matt! We need more lighting equipment questions here. I like this one.

Comment: Just a small counterpoint to an 8" softbox only good for headshots used close--it is in the more general case of wanting lotsa soft light. But if you're thinking [more noir](http://neilvn.com/tangents/flash-photography-recreating-hollywood-glamor-style-portraits/)... As with most gear, it all depends on what you want and how you use it.

Comment: @inkista Great point; I kind of touched on that but I'll expand a bit.

Comment: @mattdm No worries. I meant it as a footnote not a refutation. :)

Comment: @mattdm (or anyone who may know) - I do have two specific questions. The Canon 6D I have doesn't have built-in transmission ability; that being said, I would need multiple PocketWizards, right? One transmitter for the camera, and then one for each speedlite I deploy? 

That being said, I was thinking I could, perhaps, get away with the [Vello FreeWave trigger](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/981497-REG/vello_fwb_c_freewave_fusion_basic_wireless.html), attach it to my 430 EX II, and trigger another flash from that output.

Comment: However, the 430 EX II [doesn't have](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/43363/do-canon-430exii-speedlite-flash-units-have-an-optical-slave-function) built-in master capability, but can be triggered as a slave by the [90 EX](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/search?N=11003531&InitialSearch=yes&sts=pi) (which does). So, I can still accomplish this?

Comment: @Matt I don't actually know the details of the Canon flash system. This might help... [How can I fire a single canon 430ex flash remotely from a Canon 6D camera?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/35979/how-can-i-fire-a-single-canon-430ex-flash-remotely-from-a-canon-6d-camera)

Comment: @mattdm Oh, ok. That's one of the questions I've looked at. As I understand it, based on some of the info there and [this Canon article](http://www.learn.usa.canon.com/resources/articles/2012/eos6d_builtin_flash_alternative.shtml#showAll), the 90 EX will serve as master unit with the 430 EX II acting as a slave. So, in theory, I should be able to attach the transmitter/receiver to the 90, and trigger them both that way.

Comment: @Matt — I feel like we recently had another question about that... I think that'll only work if the trigger passes full digital information, rather than being a basic trigger which only contains the center "fire!" pin. But we should get someone who actually knows about Canon to answer.

Comment: Yeah, I know it would work if the 90's on the camera, but not sure if it will if it's off and used with a trigger, to fire the 430. I'll ask a new question to that end - easier than just hoping someone with Canon experience will answer here. Thanks again for all the help you've provided, I really do appreciate it. I'll mark you as the "answer" in a few days, after others hopefully have chimed in further.

Comment: Depends on the trigger. If the trigger is fully e-TTL and HSS compatible it should work, since the camera will see the transmitter as a compatible flash and the 90EX should see the receiver as a compatible camera. IMO the best bang for the buck system is the Yongnuo 622 system. Use the 622TX (≈$45) on camera and a 622C on the flash. You could also use a second 622C (≈$40) on camera, but it doesn't have the LCD display that simplifies making the settings you want.

Comment: +1 for the 622 system.  I have had the 622C's for a couple of years and they are great, but the recent addition of the TX was a leap in ease of use and capability.

Comment: @mattdm - Getting to the point of making a purchase, finally. Gonna go with Rapid Box; would you say that one variation (strip or octa) is better than the other, or are they both pretty similar in general use? Thanks!

Comment: @Matt Definitely different. I end up using the strip more often, because it fits my small space better and I like the dramatic sidelight effect. The octa is better as a main light, though.

Comment: @mattdm Ok. Between the octa mini and the strip, which would you recommend, if you could only have one (and were just starting out)? I'm going to be in more mobile, on-location type situations, vs. in-studio, primarily using it for head and full-body shots. I really like the idea of the strip, but would you say it's versatile enough?